# Muller's method Three Initial values

Tags: roots, nonlinear-system, initial-value-problems

[image]

I am trying to sole these two questions. I know how to do the Muller's method.
How can I find the "Three initial values(x1, x2, x3)" for question 3? My guess of initial value for question 3 is that "choose random number of x1 then increase by 0.2 for x2 and x3. (0, 0.2, 0.4).
For #4, I have no idea how to get initial values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 3, they almost tell you what initial values to use:  Use the actual root or near root (which they do tell you) and go 0.2 up and 0.2 down from there.

For question 4 they tell you explicitly to use the two end points (0 and 1) and the midpoint (0.5))